# How can I extract a string from an excel cell?

Tags: c#, string, excel, cell

I know how to write to a cell, but how do I get an already existing string written inside a cell in an excel file into a string object so I can use it to generate data in other cells?

My code so far:

```
        Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

        excelApp.Visible = true;

        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\list.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "",
        false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

        string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
        Excel.Worksheet xlws = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
```

I can manipulate cell contents using something like:

`xlws.Cells[1,1] = "foo";`

But I'm having trouble doing the opposite, that is reading cell contents into a string in my program.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>`string myString = xlws.Cells[1, 1].Value as string;`</strike>

`string myString = ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value2.ToString();`

Comment: I gave Slai an upvote because he is right when dealing with strings, you should use `Convert.ToString(object)` instead of `ToString()`. Switching this in my project just now fixed my null reference.

Answer (score 12):

To avoid `NullReferenceException`, don't use `.ToString()` directly on types that can be null (`object`, `dynamic`, `string`, etc.). Here are few safer ways to convert object to string:

- `Convert.ToString(object)` - returns [`String.Empty`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6a1a2c3ac58e60dd) when object is null
- `object?.ToString()` - VS 2015 [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) returns null if object is null
- `object?.ToString() ?? ""` - [C# null-coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to return `""` when object is null
- `object + ""` - String.Concat to return `""` when object is null
- `$"{object}"` - VS 2015 [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) is [transformed at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350790/how-is-c-sharp-string-interpolation-compiled) to invoke an equivalent `String.Format("{0}", object)` call, and returns `""` when object is null

Comment: Posts like this make me miss the SO Documentation. This would have been a perfect entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**xlws.Cells[1, 1].Value** has type **object**. So you should indicate the type
For examples:

```
xlws.Cells[1,1].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to get the values from an excel docuemnt but the way I think you're looking for is:

```
Range range = xlws.get_range("A1", "A1");
object[] data = range.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
string str = (string)data[0];
```

A nice article that explains the other ways too is available [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

string val = sheet.Cells[1, 6].Text;

This was the best method to get text from cell.
I could get just same text without any change.

Answer (score 0):

```
I can suggest one more way is (If you need to read string from row 3 column "I":
    Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
    objExcel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbook objBook = o     objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\myexcel.xlsx");
    Excel.Worksheet objsheet =  objBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    string a = Convert.ToString(objsheet.Cells.get_Item(3,"I").Value);
```