# Select substring within cell and set its style

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I can iterate over cells within worksheet. Each cell contains some text.

How can I select a substring within single cell and set its individual style?

For example underline a specific word (found by pattern or by start/end index of chars) within single cell.

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646145/how-can-i-extract-a-string-from-an-excel-cell

Comment: @Mocanu Bogdan your link is about extracting entire cell as string. It;s not possible to set it's style then.

Comment: @Ben Reading cell value, but i can access it as string only.