# How is C# string interpolation compiled?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, roslyn, c#-6.0

I know that interpolation is syntactic sugar for `string.Format()`, but does it have any special behavior/recognition of when it is being used with a string formatting method?

If I have a method:

```
void Print(string format, params object[] parameters)
```

And the following call to it using interpolation:

```
Print($"{foo} {bar}");
```

Which of the following calls lines is most equivalent to the compiled result of string interpolation?

```
Print(string.Format("{0} {1}", new[] { foo, bar }));
Print("{0} {1}", new[] { foo, bar });
```

Reasoning behind the question:  Logging frameworks such as NLog typically defer string formatting until they have determined that a log message will actually be written.  In general I prefer the string interpolation syntax, but I need to know if it may incur an extra performance penalty.

Comment: I know of a really easy way to find out. Try both and compare the generated IL.

Comment: You can use LinqPad to see IL code faster. Or any decomplie tool like JustDecomplie or Reflector

Comment: Your method is fundamentally unsafe.  What if I call it with a single string that happens to contain braces?

Comment: @SLaks It's no more safe or unsafe than `String.Format` already is? So long as it's documented in a similar way, I don't here a problem here?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: `String.Format` has the same issue, but people hopefully don't do that.  Whereas `Print($"{foo} {bar}");` is broken.

Comment: @SLaks: Of course, in the real world you would want a set of method overloads to take care of that problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is compiled in one of two ways.

If you use a string interpolation expression where a `string` is expected, it is compiled into a call to `string.Format`.

Basically, this:

```
string s = $"now is {DateTime.Now}";
```

is turned into this:

```
string s = string.Format("now is {0}", DateTime.Now);
```

[See it for yourself in Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayUAJ0iw6AXhgASAEQQ+Adxhg6TACJU0AFTDpUAOgByegL6acsx9kdA=).

Nothing magical here.

Now, on the other hand, if you use it in a place where a `FormattableString` (a new type in .NET 4.6) is expected, it is compiled into a call to [`FormattableStringFactory.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory.create(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void Test(FormattableString s)
{
}

Test($"now is {DateTime.Now}");
```

The call there is turned into this:

```
Test(FormattableStringFactory.Create("now is {0}", DateTime.Now));
```

[See it for yourself in Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayAKqhRiAJACIIfAO4wwdJgBEqaOWHSoAdADktAX1UScsmzLYuOhEuRRHu/ITAUlADE+ACd0I2QqYlQ4ZFDIWBAJNxYnbBsgA===).

So in essence, to answer your final question there:

This call:

```
Print($"{foo} {bar}");
```

Will be translated to this:

```
Print(string.Format("{0} {1}", foo, bar));
```

which will incur the cost of the formatting through `string.Format` before `Print` is even called.

If you could add, or find, an overload of `Print` that takes a `FormattableString`, then you could defer the actual cost of `string.Format` until after you've figured out if you need to log. Whether this has a measurable different in runtime is hard to say.

[See it for yourself in Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayACgCdIyAIxiAJACIIfAO4wwdJgBEqaACph0qAHQA5PQF9NEnLPlKIyAEwbtegyNTCytbB11nVxk2R2iYOM4SchQzbn4hGEVlNRRPWAAzPgV0MwAaDioFKnQ6PgIAK1RSZABtAF0YSqgQCTiWWVjZBMIkmBTkNIFhLK9fADEikuRkKmJUOGQ8sd7ZfvZYxyA===).

---

#### Bonus Round

Not only is the actual formatting deferred, but the `ToString` method of `FormattableString` allows you to specify a `IFormatProvider`.

This means that you can defer localized transformation as well.

```
public static void Print(FormattableString s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("norwegian: " + s.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO")));
    Console.WriteLine("us: " + s.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
    Console.WriteLine("swedish: " + s.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE")));
}
```

Comment: So in essence, to answer the OPs performance query, it results in a new class being constructed (`ConcreteFormattableString`, from [the factory](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Runtime/CompilerServices/FormattableStringFactory.cs,38)), but the arguments will continue to not be evaluated by the logging framework unless it calls the `ToString` method, ie it's going to end up logging it.

Comment: **If** the logging method accepts a `FormattableString`. If the logging framework accepts a `string`, it will do the formatting through `string.Format` at the call site, before the logging framework figures out if it needs to log or not.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I skipped ahead - I had already had visions in my head of having replaced all the `String` arguments in my logging wrapper with `FormattableString` :)

Comment: Note that adding an overload that accepts `FormattableString` won't help, because `string` has higher priority during overload resolution. You will have to use a separate method name.

Comment: Actually, string interpolation could compile into string concatenation in some cases (e.g. when a `int` is used).

`var a = "hello"; var b = $"{a} world";` compiles to string concatenation.
`var a = "hello"; var b = $"{a} world {1}";` compiles to string format.

Comment: @OmarMuscatello I tested this in LINQPad, it compiled to `string.Format` in both cases, how did you verify this?

Comment: I tested with ILSpy, ILDASM and [the tool](https://sharplab.io) you provided in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps in a newer version of the compiler then? https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQFEAeAHJzkCWA9gHYBqUCBUwANigDQwgG0A+AAgAwAEHAjAG4AsACgOAZj4AmHgGEeAbzE9VfKRwAsPALIAKAJRKVa0wDdKPKDwC8PAEQALCLVpF7gnhYQ9gtngAk9opQAL48AO5ECLQAJh4mqqFioUA - switching to a newer version there does indeed use string concatenation.