# LINQ GroupBy while converting from string to decimal and then back to string

Tags: linq, lambda, group-by, type-conversion

Is it possible to convert a string value to a decimal value within a LINQ expression that performs an aggregate function like SUM or AVERAGE?

Assume the example below where I have a collection of Bank Accounts where my goal is to obtain an average of each customers bank account if they have a balance. The data comes from an XML API where all the data is read in a strings.

```
public class BankAccount
{
  string Id{ get; set; }
  string CustomerId { get; set; }
  string Balance { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data ...

```
{ Id = "1", CustomerId = "Bob", Balance = "1" }
{ Id = "2", CustomerId = "Bob", Balance = "2" }
{ Id = "3", CustomerId = "Sam", Balance = "4" }
{ Id = "4", CustomerId = "Sam", Balance = "" }
{ Id = "5", CustomerId = "Alice", Balance = "" }
```

LINQ grouping expression. Is there a way to convert the value of Balance to a decimal so an average can be taken within the LINQ statement? I tried `x => Decimal.Parse(x.Balance)` but got an `Input string was not in a correct format` error. I only need to convert the `Balance` property to decimal for the Average calculation as the results would be rendered as a string in the XML.

At the same time, if an account does not have a balance listed (i.e. it's blank like Sams's first account and Alice's only account above) then I don't want the Average to take that entry included in the average, though I still want the account grouped in for display.

```
var groupedResults = allAccounts
                      .GroupBy(x => new {x.CustomerId, x.Balance})
                      .Select(g => new BankAccount {
                         CustomerId = g.Customer.Key.CustomerId,
                         Balance = g.Average(x => x.Balance)
                      }).ToList();
```

These are the results I am looking for:

```
{ CustomerId = "Bob", Balance = "1.5" }
{ CustomerId = "Sam", Balance = "4" }
{ CustomerId = "Alice", Balance = "" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achieve the result you are looking for you should try this:

```
var groupedResults = allAccounts
                      .GroupBy(x =>x.CustomerId)
                      .Select(g => new BankAccount {
                         CustomerId = g.Key,
                         Balance = g.Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Balance))
                                    .Select(x =>(decimal?)decimal.Parse(x.Balance))
                                    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                                    .Average().ToString()
                      }).ToList();
```

First just group by `CustomerId`, is not necessary to include the `Balance` there. Then, to get the average and avoid the error parsing include the condition to make sure the `Balance` is not empty.

Another way to do it using query syntax:

```
from e in allAccounts
group e by e.CustomerId into g
let temp=g.Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Balance))
select new BankAccount(){CustomerId = g.Key,
                         Balance =temp.Any()? 
                                  temp.Average(x =>Decimal.Parse(x.Balance)).ToString():""
                        };
```

Comment: average of 4 and 0 would result in 2, but there are few ways around it

Comment: @Slai - In this case if Balance is empty or blank I don't want to include it in the average. Basically I don't want to treat a blank value as zero.

Comment: @webworm, sorry, I misunderstood the part of you don't wan't to include the items with blank values, you will need to add a where to exclude them, see my update

Comment: When I try using the Lambda syntax I get an error `cannot implicitly convert type decimal? to string`

Comment: Did you put the `.ToString()` at the end? I tested yesterday in LinqPad and it worked

Comment: I did add the `.ToString` however what ended up making work was removing the extra right parens after Average and removing the semicolon after `.ToString()`. I had the advantage of intellisense :)

Comment: haha, its true, I should have copy the same query I wrote in LinqPad, sorry about the syntax errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal d;
var groupedResults = allAccounts.GroupBy(a => a.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => new BankAccount { CustomerId = g.Key, Balance = g.Average(b => 
        decimal.TryParse(b.Balance, out d) ? (decimal?)d : null).ToString() }).ToList();
```

The `.TryParse` part results in `(decimal?)null` for strings that can't be parsed, which are then [ignored by `.Average`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,79ed961a51d53d47). Also, the last average for Alice results in `(decimal?)null` and then in `""`.

Comment: @webworm that's what my answer is doing .. null values are not used in the average

Comment: Sorry, I see what your saying now. By treating blank as zero you would be throwing off the average. Your solutions avoids that. Very nice.

Comment: Would there be a problem when trying to apply `.ToString()` to a `null` value?

Comment: @webworm on most types yes, but in my case `null(decimal?).ToString()` returns `""` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,d83d2db767b43db7. I have an answer on avoiding `.ToString()` if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646145/how-can-i-extract-a-string-from-an-excel-cell/41127000#41127000

Comment: can you pass in the `out var d` without `d` being declared? Compiler is giving me an error.

Comment: @webworm updated it for earlier versions C# before Visual Studio 2015